# parsing api response JSON to get content values

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

**Background**

I have an ios app that is receiving a response from a post call. I am simply trying to extract the id in the content tag. But all the syntax that I see on help pages do not seem to work.

```
self.post("stands/build", data: dataDictionary).responseString { (response) -> Void in
     let responseValue = response.result.value
     let new_data =  JSON(responseValue!)
     print(new_data)
     print(new_data[0])
     print(new_data["message"])
     print(new_data["content"])
```

prints:

```
{"message":"Success","content":{"id":351,"user_id":2,"name":"test","creator":null,"size":0,"description":"Test"}}
null
null
null
```

I am using `import SwiftyJSON`

**Question:**

What code would print the user id: 351.

I was under the impression that `print(new_data["content]["id"])` would work, but it just gives nulls

**EDIT 1**

```
            if let dataFromString = responseValue!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {

                //SwiftyJSON, construct JSON.
                let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
                print(json["content"]["id"])

            }
```

causes this error:

```
2016-07-19 14:17:15.888 MYPROJECT[13799:3666542] -[__NSCFDictionary dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffe2e0416a0
2016-07-19 14:17:15.946 MYPROJECT[13799:3666542] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffe2e0416a0'
```

**EDIT 2**

```
let id: Int = JSON["content"]["id"].intValue
```

gives the error `instance member 'subscript' cannot be used on type 'JSON'`

**EDIT 3 almost there...**

```
self.post("stands/build", data: dataDictionary).responseString { (response) -> Void in
    let responseValue = response.result.value
    let new_dict = (responseValue as! NSDictionary) 
    print(new_dict["content"]!["id"])
```

prints `Optional(356)`

How do I make it print 356?

**EDIT 4**

```
print(new_dict["content"]!["id"]!!.intValue)
```

works.

Though, I think my solution is sloppy. None of the solutions below worked for, but I will upvote the solution that led me to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
if let new_data =  JSON(responseValue!) as? NSDictionary{
    let content = new_data["content"] as! NSdictionary 
    let user_id = content[user_id] as! Int  
    print(format:"user_id :: %d",user_id)
}
else{ 
   print("no data found..")
}
```

Comment: this prints "no data found.." every time, ill try and figure out why

Comment: @Rorschach It is happening because `JSON(data: dataFromString)` is not converting data into NSDictionary

Comment: Can you take a look at EDIT 3 in my question, I used part of your solution to get myself closer

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `int` property of JSON object.

A quick-simple example:

```
if let id: Int = json["someData"]["someValue"].int {
  // id was defined properly
}
else {
  print("parsing error: \(json["someData"]["someValue"])")
}
```

Or you can get some value always using `intValue`

```
let id: Int = json["someData"]["someValue"].intValue // defines some value or zero as fallback
```

I hope this can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: `let id: Int = JSON["content"]["id"].intValue` gives the error `instance member 'subscript' cannot be used on type 'JSON'`

Answer (score 0):

From the log,

Firstly, responseValue is not a JSON object, it's just a json string.
If so,

```
if let dataFromString = responseValue.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {

    //SwiftyJSON, construct JSON.
    let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
    print(json["content"]["id"])

}
```

This should work!